# data frame selecting data using a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have a data frame looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

data = {'datetime' : ['2009-07-24 02:00:00', '2009-07-24 03:00:00','2009-07-24 04:00:00'],
     'value1' : ['a', np.nan ,'c'],
     'value2' : ['d','e','f']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']))
missing = df.loc[:, df.columns != ('datetime')]
```

the data above is just a sample. but let say I have a lot of missing values in bigger data. I want to select all the data with missing values in 'value1' column.

```
missing_index = df[df['value1'].isnull()].index
```

this code will let get me all the indices of missing values, but I want the actual rows of them, in this case, second row.

So, I tried,

```
df[missing_index]
```

but I am having an error saying

> KeyError: "DatetimeIndex(['2009-07-24 03:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None) not in index"

Comment: `df[df['value1'].isnull()]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the fact that `df[<something>]` is used to get columns. When you call `df[missing_index]` it's trying to find the `missing_index` in the columns (which is also an Index).

The easiest way to do what you want is as @panktijk pointed out in his comment:

```
df[df['value1'].isnull()]
```

However, if for some reason (maybe you want to manipulate them) you want to go your way where you first get the indexes and then use those to pull your sub-dataframe, you could do the following:

```
df.loc[missing_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using index to capure the row number:(begin to 0)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'datetime' : ['2009-07-24 02:00:00', '2009-07-24 03:00:00','2009-07-24 04:00:00', '2009-07-24 05:00:00'],
     'value1' : ['a', np.nan ,'c', np.nan],
     'value2' : ['d','e','f', 'g']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']))

listofnan = df.index[df['value1'].isnull()].tolist()

for i in listofnan:
    print(df.index.get_loc(i))
```

result:

```
1
3
```